# An "standard computer power supply"

Tags: atx

I'm trying to use an ATX connector.

https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9498?gclid=CjwKEAiAjsunBRCy3LSlz_PJqCgSJACJY7yKBmbtZzitS08I2EKyfFqex4UVlCzSfHP8GdYK2TNvChoCrkPw_wcB

In the product description, it says, *"Pair this connector with a standard computer power supply"*. I have a standard Macbook Pro with Retina display.

Does that mean I have to use my mag-safe 2, or a USB cable?

Comment: I still am unsure what the question really is. I see an ATX connector for an ATX power supply to be used on a laptop (?) and the question asking about USB or "mag-safe 2". I'm really confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither. It means that you have to use a [ATX power supply](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATX#Power_supply). The ATX power supply is a standard for PC style computers.

Comment: What is that? Is that cheap?

Comment: It's a computer part. It costs however much your computer part supplier charges for it.